# Groovy "not instanceof" peculiarity

Tags: groovy, instanceof

I have discovered behaviour that I hadn't anticipated within Groovy 2.4.7, 1.6.0 JVM when attempting to evaluate a *not* instanceof condition.

in summary:

```
class Foo {    
    static Boolean bar() {
      String x = "Personally, I don't really like King Crimson"
      return (!x instanceof Integer)
    }    
}
```

I would anticipate that Foo.bar() would return true because x is *not* an instance of Integer however Foo.bar() returns false.  In contrast the following returns true:

```
class Foo {    
    static Boolean bar() {
      String x = "Personally, I don't really like King Crimson"
      return !(x instanceof Integer)
    }    
}
```

The issue is academic, but out of curiousity: is this a bug in the language or have I misunderstood how instanceof is supposed to work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a case of [operator precedence](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_operator_precedence)...

`!` occurs before `instanceof`, so it's actually checking:

```
(!x) instanceof Integer
```

So it's converting String to a boolean (`!'Hello'` is `false` as the string contains some text.

Then seeing if the boolean is an instanceof Integer (which it isn't)

hence `false`

If you put the `!` outside the brackets (as in your second version) then it does the instanceof first, and negates the result, giving you the answer you'd expect

### Edit for Groovy 3+

In groovy 3 there's a new way of doing this using `!instanceof`:

```
return x !instanceof Integer
```

Comment: Dude, I love you so much right now (in a very platonic way ;) ... Coming from PHP I was scratching my hair why this didn't work.